# Has many through associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following associations which works well.

```
class Indicator < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :statement, required: false
  belongs_to :identity, required: false
end

class Statement < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :indicators   
  has_many :identities, :through => :indicators 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :identities
end

class Identity < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :indicators   
  has_many :statements, :through => :indicators 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :statements
end
```

My form is as follows. I want to be able to add a model in called `Phases`. So for each `statement` there can be many `identities` and for each of those identities i would like to associate a `phase` using a select tag, and then be able to call in the show view. I'm unsure how best to implement this.

```
<%= form_with(model: statement, local: true) do |form| %>
 <table class="table table-bordered">
  <% hidden_field_tag "statement[identity_ids][]", nil %>
   <% Identity.all.each do |b| %>
    <tr>
     <td><%= check_box_tag "statement[identity_ids][]", b.id, @statement.identity_ids.include?(b.id) %></td>
     <td><%= b.description %></td>
     <td>CODE FOR PHASES</td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
 </table>

 <div class="actions">
  <%= form.submit %>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

Show View

```
<table>
 <th>Description</th>
 <th>Phase</th>
 <% @statement.identities.each do |l| %>
 <tr>
  <td><%= l.description %></td>
  <td><% l.phases.each do |n| %><%= n.name %><% end %></td>
  Even tried this and same result.
  <td><%= l.phases.pluck(:name) %></td>
 </tr>
 <% end %>
</table>
```

I have added a image below of the table structure i'm think of (unsure if possible) and the end product.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**app/controllers/statements_controller.rb**

```
class StatementsController < ApplicationController
  # ...
  private

  def statement_params
    params.fetch(:statement, {})
      .permit(indicators_attributes: [:id, :_destroy, :identity_id, :phase_id])
  end
end
```

**app/models/statement.rb**

```
class Statement < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :indicators
  has_many :identities, through: :indicators
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :indicators, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :all_blank
end
```

**app/views/statements/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_with(model: @statement, local: true) do |f| %>
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
      <th>Indicator Description</th>
      <th>Phase</th>
      <th>Remove?</th>
    </tr>
    <% Identity.all.each do |identity| %>
      <%= f.fields_for :indicators, f.object.indicators.where(identity: identity).first_or_initialize do |ff| %>
        <%= ff.hidden_field :id %>
        <%= ff.hidden_field :identity_id %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= ff.object.identity.description %></td>
          <td><%= ff.select :phase_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Phase.all, :id, :name, ff.object.phase_id), include_blank: true %></td>
          <td><%= ff.check_box :_destroy %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </table>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

[image]

```
<form action="/statements" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="quj6ylAE1l+730pQ/YvOxkv1pfJlBb7yj0TPmb8GCkj7A90PRufHFzyIvw53zcFE1ZeyJB8TCZDqho9vJPpyUQ==">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <tbody><tr>
      <th>Indicator Description</th>
      <th>Phase</th>
      <th>Remove?</th>
    </tr>

        <input type="hidden" name="statement[indicators_attributes][0][id]" id="statement_indicators_attributes_0_id">
        <input type="hidden" value="1" name="statement[indicators_attributes][0][identity_id]" id="statement_indicators_attributes_0_identity_id">
        <tr>
          <td>ABC</td>
          <td><select name="statement[indicators_attributes][0][phase_id]" id="statement_indicators_attributes_0_phase_id"><option value=""></option>
<option value="1">Phase 1</option>
<option value="2">Phase 2</option></select></td>
          <td><input name="statement[indicators_attributes][0][_destroy]" type="hidden" value="0"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="statement[indicators_attributes][0][_destroy]" id="statement_indicators_attributes_0__destroy"></td>
        </tr>

        <input type="hidden" name="statement[indicators_attributes][1][id]" id="statement_indicators_attributes_1_id">
        <input type="hidden" value="2" name="statement[indicators_attributes][1][identity_id]" id="statement_indicators_attributes_1_identity_id">
        <tr>
          <td>DEF</td>
          <td><select name="statement[indicators_attributes][1][phase_id]" id="statement_indicators_attributes_1_phase_id"><option value=""></option>
<option value="1">Phase 1</option>
<option value="2">Phase 2</option></select></td>
          <td><input name="statement[indicators_attributes][1][_destroy]" type="hidden" value="0"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="statement[indicators_attributes][1][_destroy]" id="statement_indicators_attributes_1__destroy"></td>
        </tr>
  </tbody></table>

  <div class="actions">
    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Create Statement" data-disable-with="Create Statement">
  </div>
</form>
```

**app/views/statements/show.html.erb**

```
<table>
  <th>Description</th>
  <th>Phase</th>
  <% @statement.indicators.each.do |indicator| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= indicator.identity.description %></td>
      <td><%= indicator.phase.name %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

[image]

*Tested Working*

Comment: Wonderful @Jay. Appreciate the help. Only problem I'm facing is in the show.html.erb. The problem is with listing the corresponding phase with the identity, unique for the statement. At the moment it lists all phases with the matching identity_id. I'll add my show.html.erb above.

Comment: @DollarChills No prob! :) I updated my answer; hopefully that's what you were asking for (see show.html.erb and some screenshots above)

Comment: @DollarChills, by the way, you might want to remove this: `reject_if: :all_blank` (see my models/statement.rb above) if you want to persist all Indicators-for-each-identity

Comment: Absolutely spot on. You are a gentleman and a scholar. I appreciate your help on this, been driving me bonkers!

Comment: Wondering if you have any good reference material based on this method? In regards to calling the object in the form?

Comment: @DollarChills No problem! :) Glad to help! Regarding `f.object` above, I just stumbled upon knowing it when inspecting/debugging code inside the form (i.e. I inserted `<%= byebug %>` just right after `form_for` or `fields_for`). But, seems like it's in the Rails documentation (See the "Attributes" section): http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html though it's very discretely shown and not even described/documented properly, in my opinion.

Comment: By the way `f.object` just basically equals the object you passed into `form_with ... do |f|` which is `@statement`. Similarly, `ff.object` just basically equals the object you passed into `f.fields_for ... do |ff|` which is `f.object.indicators.where(identity: identity).first_or_initialize` which of course (by definition above) is also equal to `@statement.indicators.where(identity: identity).first_or_initialize`.

Comment: Thank you once again @jay. Really appreciate you taking the time to help.